# Get output stream Python

Tags: java, python, output, exec, exe

I am calling a python script from a java program on my server with SSH/Shell and I want to have the print statements from the Python script appear in the output, how can I get the output stream in the python script and print/log to it?

Answer (score 0):

`Expect` is a tool that handles such interaction on the command line. No need to change your python script, just print it to stdout.

My best advice is to have a look at the java implementations of expect:

- simple: https://github.com/ronniedong/Expect-for-Java
- more complex implementations: http://expectj.sourceforge.net and http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/